# React.js - "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui, array-map

I have tried the methods that I found by searching but none of that work? Why it's still showing that `map` is undefined?

````
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

class ComboBox extends React.Component {

  state ={
    option : []
  }
  async componentDidMount(){
  const url = await 'https://api.covid19india.org/data.json';
  const response =await fetch(url);
  const data = response.json();
  const pop = data.statewise.map(st=>st.state);
  this.setState({option : pop})

  }


  render(){
    return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={(this.state.option)}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );}
}

export default  ComboBox```
````

Comment: What is the data object structure? Can you please share by loggin it to the console?

Comment: well i got the answer, actually, it returns  a list of the Indian states

Answer (score 2):

`response.json()` return a `promise`. you should change the line

```
  const data = response.json();
```

to

```
  const data = await response.json();
```

And, by the way, using `await` in `const url = await 'https://api.covid19india.org/data.json';` is redundant